# Angular Getting Started Step 4 - Changes not reflected on app page

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn Angular following this guide: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

I am on a Mac and have followed everything (to my knowledge) it says, and after serving up the page using  `ng serve --open` like it says to, when I make a change to my app.component.ts file and save, the web browser not only doesn't refresh, but even when I manually refresh, the content doesn't reflect the change I made.

I tried this - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4329#issuecomment-276820364 - but it didn't work.

What else can I try? It's very frustrating to try learning something and not even make it off the first page!

Comment: I am using Sublime Text to make changes to my ts file. I don't know if that makes a difference but wanted to make sure that was disclosed.

Comment: does your terminal displays any error ?

Comment: I've had similar issues with the angular cli.  What has worked for me in the past is deleting the `node_modules` folder then running the following commands `npm update`, `npm install`.  After that `ng serve` worked for me.